# Post mongo aggregation, can I merge a document with another document on a matching key?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Say I run a Mongo aggregate query and get a result set back, containing documents in the form,

```
{ user_id : 1234, value : 678 }
```

Is it possible to take the returned documents from the aggregation query and match the user_id to documents in a user collection then merge the result. i.e  Match the above document to a user record with the form,

```
{_id : 1234, name : bob knight, email : bob@bob }
```

and return

```
{_id : 1234, name : bob knight, email : bob@bob, value : 678 }
```

Comment: If the records which you want to compare and merge are in two different collections then it is not possible and you might have to do it in using a program or script.

Comment: They are in the same collection. The aggregate $match is matching on a different key than the user docs.

Comment: looks like you asked the same question on google groups - what exactly do you want to do if you can match/combine them? i.e. is there a one-to-one correspondence here?  or could one _id:1234 have several "user_id":1234, value:xxx documents and if so, how should they be combined?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming either there is one value doc per user or you want to add them if there are multiple, you can do this:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
     {$project:{user_id:{$ifNull:["$user_id","$_id"]}, email:1,name:1,value:1}},
     {$group:{_id:"$user_id",name:{$max:"$name"}, email:{$max:"$email"},value:{$sum:"$value"}}}
)
```

$project needs to add user_id field into the documents with _id, hence the $ifNull.
$group just groups them, summing value works because null is 0, and $max works for the other fields because any value is > null.